# How can i get and display all value without undefined value from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

How can i get and display all value without undefined value from mongodb?

```
app.post('/add_teacher',(req,res)=>{
    const name = req.body.name;
    const biography = req.body.biography;
  teacherCollection.insertOne({name,biography})
         .then(result =>{
           console.log(result);
             res.send(result.insertedCount>0);            
        })                  
    }) 

app.get('/get_all_teacher', (req, res) =>{

  teacherCollection.find()
  .toArray((err, course) =>{
   res.send(course);
  })
})
```

suppose,i give a value for name but don't give value for biography.so the value of biography will be "undefined".now i want to get nothing where value is "undefined" .I have used mongodb

https://i.stack.imgur.com/39qHH.jpg

Comment: can you add your `document` to your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide a minimal example of what you tried so far and where you struggle at :)

Comment: @AminTaghikhani  please check now.

Answer (score 0):

In `javascript` when you want to access a `key` from an `object` and the `key` is not exists in `object` it return `undefiend`

```
const biography = req.body.biography; // return undefiend if not exists
```

if you want `null` value or a `default` value when the `key` is not exists, this code will help you

```
const biography = req.body.biography || null; // return null if not exists

const biography = req.body.biography || ''; // return empty string if not exists
```

Comment: But why i can't return empty string more than one .

Comment: more detail please.

Comment: For example,                                                                                                                
 const biography = req.body.biography || ''; const name = req.body.name|| ''; const age= req.body.age || ''; the result of boigraphy will be  " " but return "undefined" for  name and age .is it posible to get " " for all input?

Comment: yes it's possible to get `''` for all input, can you log your `req.body` and send for me?